# Traversing through a dict of lists of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, traversal

I have a dict that contains a combination of dicts and lists, the format generally looks like:

```
dict={
    category1: {
        [{sub_cat1: [{item1:datetime1},
                     {item2:val2}
                    ],
          sub_cat2: 'some-string',
          sub_cat3: some_int},
         {sub_cat1: [{item1:datetime3},
                     {item2:val4}
                    ],
          sub_cat2: 'some-string2',
          sub_cat3: some_int2},
                    .
                    .
        ],
    category2:{[]},
    category3:{[{some more stuff}]}
    }
```

The purpose is to modify the datetime object inside the the lowest hierarchy directly in dict. I can write a giant `for` loop to iterate through everything, but I don't know if there's a more efficient way to traverse through this dict.

Comment: More efficient in terms of performance or amount of code?

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: You probably want to use a recursive function that accepts either a list or a dict and iterates through it looking for datetimes, and if it finds a list or dict, just feeds that back to the recursive function.  Hopefully, you don't have any circular references.

Comment: Is that a typo where `category1: { [], category2:[], }` should have the value as a list [ not a dictionary containing a list? As written, it will complain that the key is unhashable...

Comment: @Alex Hall, if possible then definitely both, otherwise performance

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes, that's my fault. there should an additional bracket outside of each list to stay consistent with category1

Comment: @JChao There also isn't a key there.

Comment: @Natecat I got lazy and didnt complete category2. It's the same format as category1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traversing into arbitrarily-nested iterables is generally done with a recursive function, such as this:

```
def change_datetime(new_datetime, dct):
    temp = enumerate(dct) if isinstance(dct, list) else dct.items()
    for index, i in :
        if hasattr(i, "__iter__"):
            change_datetime(new_datetime, i)
        elif isinstance(i, datetime.datetime):
            dct[index] = i
```

By the new call to change_datetime every time we find another iterable, we can check each list/dict in the hierarchy.

Comment: Also, you can use the `collections` module to test for "iterableness".  `import collections; isinstance(i, collections.Iterable)`; though, you may want to explicitly check for lists/dicts, since strings will return true for "iterableness" as well.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I don't want to include strings though, just other data containers.

Comment: Yes, this is concise and works well! Thanks for your answer

Comment: `>>> hasattr("", "__iter__")
False`
I assume python2